# Windows command: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: windows, cmd

Why is this command incorrect on Windows?

```
mkdir dist && copy node_modules/todomvc-app-css/index.css public/todomvc-app-css.css
```

Comment: Backslash, not slash

Comment: thank you, can you make an answer? I'll accept it straight away

Comment: DOS has been dead for decades. It's highly unlikely you're using Window and DOS, unless you're still using a very, very old version of Windows.

Comment: @KenWhite interesting, actually this is a command for a tool like Webpack to execute (Javascript bundler). This command is in a package.json configuration file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use backslashes, not slashes in your paths.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS(Operational System) is windows, you have to use \ instead of /, as the System can't read it and execute in the same fashion as linux and IOS using /.

Another example of application would be in Apache Airflow which they request the use of mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins  , but it only works with the usage of \ instead of /.